# Сокращение кода

Tags: c#, razor, оптимизация

Недавно начал изучать asp.net. Подскажите, пожалуйста, могу ли я сократить этот код, чтобы не создавать переменную. Реализовать полноценный if не хочется, он еще огромней. Поудалять пробелы не вариант.

```
<span>
   @{var version = string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.Version) ? "1" : file.Version;}
   @version;
</span>
```

Comment: код как код, бывает и больше. Что тут сокрщать-то?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно, razor воспринимает любой код, как нормальный код C#, только окончание ищет по-другому. Поэтому надо добавить приоритет:

```
@(string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.Version) ? "1" : file.Version)
```